# ADD 7 days to string formatted date

Tags: teradata

I have a varchar date in my table formatted as 20060918 and I want to be able to add 7 days to this date, and keep it valid (it would give me an invalid date if I tried to just +7)
This is my code

```
SELECT cast (WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')+ INTERVAL '7' DAY
from Analytics.Workday as WD;
```

but I'm getting an error

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [2666 : 22007] Invalid date supplied for Workday.Adjusted_Hire_Date.
```

Should I convert the Adjusted_Hire_Date column before?

Comment: The string has no dashes, so shouldn't that be `'YYYYMMDD'`?

Comment: Still getting the same error even if I removed the dashes

Comment: Do you have the option of converting the VARCHAR column into a DATE column, or would it break too many other things?

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that, can I cast it in the query?

Comment: The problem is that you have values in that column that aren't exactly like `YYYY-MM-DD` (or 'YYYYMMDD' if you are using that). You will have to clean your data first before you can cast. This is why dates stored as strings sends shivers down everyone's spine.

Comment: @JNevill I have the date as 20060918 so it is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: You only have one row in this table? If any row in this table has a malformed date string, this query will throw that error.

Comment: You can attempt to filter out bad dates first before casting with something like: `WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(mydate, '^[0-9]{8}$') = 1
    AND SUBSTR(mydate, 1, 4) <> '0000'
    AND SUBSTR(mydate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
    AND SUBSTR(mydate, 7, 2) BETWEEN 0 AND 31`

Comment: What if you try a simple: `SELECT CAST ('20060918' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')`.  Does that work?  Maybe you have some values in your table that don't match the `FORMAT` expression and are causing this error.

Comment: I found that `SELECT CAST((substr('20190522',1,4) || '-' || substr('20190522',5,2) || '-' || substr('20190522',7,2)) as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '7' DAY` works in [Teradata SQL Assistant/Web Edition Trial](http://tunweb.teradata.ws/trial/). So you could replace `'20190522'` with `WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date`. Performance will be horrible compared to what it could be with an actual date column.

Comment: @Lisa I just tried ravioli's suggestion in the aforementioned online utility and it worked. Could it be that there is bad data in that column?

Comment: This will work If there's no bad data: `to_date(Adjusted_Hire_Date, 'yyyymmdd') + 7`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Workday (employee_id,Adjusted_Hire_Date) select '3','20060918';

SELECT WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date 
  ,cast (trim(WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date) as date format 'YYYYMMDD')+ 7
from Workday as WD where employee_id=3;

Result:

[Adjusted_Hire_Date]    [Adjusted_Hire_Date+7]

20060918                9/25/2006
```